# Переопределение методов для массивов

Tags: c#

Вопрос к любознательным гуру C#.

В книге CLR via C# есть неплохой пример расширения класса StringBuilder, цель автора воссоздать метод IndexOf, который есть у простого string.

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    public static Int32 IndexOf(this StringBuilder sb, char value)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < sb.Length; index++)
            if (sb[index] == value) return index;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Взяв за основание этот пример, захотелось попробовать реализовать нечто подобное для класса Array.

Например для вывода в консоль содержащихся в массиве данных пробую сделать следующее:

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static String ToString(this int[] arr)
    {
        string str = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
            str += arr[i] + " ";
        return str;
    }
}
```

Только вот попытка вызвать неявный ToString(), вызывает стандартный GetType.ToString(). Как можно обойти это ограничение? Переопределить неявное преобразование?

Код вызова из программы:

```
int[] arr = new int[5]{23,24,66,33,7};
Console.WriteLine(arr);
```

Comment: Так это работать не будет. `ToString`, вызываемый `Console.WriteLine` не имеет никакого отношения к Вашему методу расширения. Ваш метод (и класс `ArrayExtensions`) там внутри просто не виден. Вызывайте:  `Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString());`

Comment: @Igor, `Console.WriteLine(arr.ToString())` не должно сработать, потому что instance методы проверяются перед методами расширения

Comment: Хорошо, тогда: `Console.WriteLine(ArrayExtensions.ToString(arr));`

Comment: @Igor, но тогда нет смысла делать расширение :-)

Comment: @Grundy Согласен. Я, признаться, смысла в расширениях вообще не вижу.

Comment: Данное действие как факт бессмысленно, тут важно понять сам факт, какой метод имеет приоритет, и как его можно переопределить насильственным образом )

Comment: _как его можно переопределить насильственным образом_ - никак

Comment: два решения, оба так себе: декоратор для класса Array, с правильным методом ToString, и прозрачным вызовом методов самого Array; Кастомный статический класс AsvancedConsole с дополнительными перегрузками методов для нужных типов, по принципу тот же декоратор, но с поправкой на статическую природу класса Console

Answer (score 0):

При одинаковых именах встроенные (в класс или в его родителей) методы имеют приоритет перед методами расширения. Выход - используйте другое имя. Либо вызывайте его так: `ArrayExtensions.ToString(arr);` (хотя смысла в этом мало)